# Is there any way to put ads in live wallpaper directly on live wallpaper screen?

Tags: java, android, admob, live-wallpaper

I have read questions on stack overflow but they are all about putting ads on live wallpaper preview screen or settings screen.I am using libgdx to develop live wallpapers.I followed steps used to create ads in games but it shows error.How should i proceed.

```
private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
 gameView = initializeForView(new LiveWallpaperStarter(), cfg);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
 gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
 return gameView;
```

}

I get null pointer exception while creating this gameView.

```
public class LiveWallpaperAndroid extends AndroidLiveWallpaperService {
```

this is first line of this class.

Comment: have you noted that google doesnot allow displaying ads outside your application. It was like that when I started

Comment: Is the livewallpaper i created not my application.

Comment: yes it is but it was worth mentioning because I once a college of mine showed ads outside his app and had to change it

Comment: It would help people to help you if you could post the section of log file with the error in it and the section of code it points to.